# Eclipse plugin for automatic help search of a selected text

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am currently trying to make an Eclipse plugin where you select text from the editor, press a shortcut(in my case it's alt+F1) and the Eclipse help search opens and automatically searches for that selected text.

Now, I already made the Binding->Command->Handler and the text selection in a method that returns the selected text as a string and I got stuck on how to open the Eclipse help search and query for that specific string through my code.

I searched a bit and found ISearchEngine2 from org.eclipse.help.search that could help me do what I'm trying to do, but since I'm new to Eclipse plugin development I don't really know how to implement it.

Could anybody help me with this?

My code currently looks like this:

```
    public class Button1 extends AbstractHandler {

        public Button1() {}

            public String getCurrentSelection()
            {
            IEditorPart part =PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
            if (part instanceof ITextEditor)
            {
            final ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) part;
            ISelection sel = editor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
            if (sel instanceof TextSelection)
            {
                 ITextSelection textSel = (ITextSelection) sel;
                 return textSel.getText();
            }
            }
            return null;
            }

public void searchInHelp(String str){
...
}

        public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
            IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
            String str = getTextSelection();
            searchInHelp(str);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean something like a `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `G`.

Comment: Something like that, but in the Eclipse Help, and using a certain scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ISearchEngine2` is for the engine that actually implements the help system.

Plugins that want to use the help system use the `IWorkbenchHelpSystem` interface:

```
IWorkbenchHelpSystem help = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem();

help.search("help search expression");
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for. But say I want to add a scope so this search will only search in, let's say, Workbench User Guide. How can I do that using the HelpSystem?

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear that IWorkbenchHelpSystem can specify a scope. It might be possible to specify something in the search expression but I don't know what.

Comment: Well apparently I should look for another way to set the scope, maybe using another interface, or at least some workaround could be done. Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer, it really saved me a couple of hours of searching and now my plugin works almost as intended.

Comment: Everything I can find that deals with the scope is in an internal package so is not intended for use by other plugins.